# How to check length of added text in a WPF TextBox TextChange event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TextChanged` event for my WPF TextBox as follows:

```
private void textMatch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var m = e.Changes;//here I can see e.Changes has what I'm looking for
    //do some other stuff here.
}
```

However, what I want to do is to check the length of text that was added. Apparently, `e.Changes` contains that value but I can't figure out a way to find it out *programmatically* neither could I find any example online.

*My current way of checking this is by storing the current length each time text is changed and making sure the new length only increases by 1 but It's sorta like hacking to me.*

Has anyone tried this before? How do I find out the length of the added text using the `TextChangedEventArgs`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is how to extract the `TextChange` object from the `e.Changes` TextChange collection. The following should work:

```
int added = e.Changes.ElementAt(0).AddedLength;
```

However, if you want something that *looks more specific* you could use:

```
int added = e.Changes.FirstOrDefault().AddedLength;
```

Since `e.Changes` as far as I know *at the moment* will always contain a single `TextChange` item, I guess it will always be the first even in future implementations of the WPF TextBox.

**For Non-Linq** implementation which *seems really unnecessary to me* you can use the following bulky code:

```
var x = e.Changes.GetEnumerator();
x.MoveNext();
int added = x.Current.AddedLength;
```

Comment: Works great, though I had to add `using System.Linq;` but isn't there a *constant* way of doing this? Will 0 **always** retrieve the information even if there are multiple changes? What about without LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

For a TextBox, it seems the count will always be 1, since a TextBox cannot contain anything other than characters.

But I found this searching for answers concerning the TextChange and just want to provide others with the knowledge that TextChange.Changes.Count can be greater than 1 when used with a RichTextBox.

This result can be a bit confusing.

If you are just learning to work with this, be aware that regardless of whether you enter a single character or paste multiple lines, the Count can be 1.

But a Font Family change can include multiple changes, in fact it seems 1 per selected word the changed Font Family was applied to. 
However, on the other hand, changes to Font Size, Underline, Bold, or Italic can result in Count = 0.

With a RichTextBox, a TextChange results from a symbol change, not a character change. Thus, you can paste "Hello To All The World" and get a single TextChange because it is a single TextElement containing the text pasted.